# Receber Email com Android Java

Tags: java, android, email

Eu tenho essa tela simples

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="217dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:hint="Email:"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="213dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="277dp"
        android:onClick="receberEmail"
        android:text="Enviar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etEmail" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

E tenho meu MainActivity

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText etEmail;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    }

    public void receberEmail(View view) {
        String emailDoUsuario = etEmail.getText().toString();
        //mandar email para o emailDoUsuario
    }
}
```

Eu preciso fazer com que o usuario receba um email, ou seja, meu algoritmo vai enviar um email para o `emailDoUsuario`, eu ja consegui guardar o email do usuario em uma variavel, mas como faço pra enviar um email para este endereço?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso

```
String assunto = "assunto teste";
String mensagem = "mensagem teste";

Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailDoUsuario);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, assunto);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mensagem);
email.setType("message/rfc822");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "email"));
```

Comment: Funcionou mas não como eu preciso... Eu não quero que o Usuário envie um e-mail, eu quero que o Usuário receba um email, entendeu?